# Running Android Junit test using maven with only source apk

Tags: android, maven-3

As we know that when we use robotium, we only need the apk of the source and then we can create the test case for that application. Is it possible for maven also, where I just have a apk of the source and have written the test source in robotium. Can I run this in maven version 3.0.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Using the application of morseflash. Download the application from github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples